# Error Converting DateTime to Date

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I am calling a stored procedure from a WCF service using Linq-to-sql. The function signature is defined in the designer file as:

```
public int MS_SetTimeKeeperRecord( ... global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.ParameterAttribute(Name="ReportDate", DbType="Date")] System.Nullable<System.DateTime> reportDate, ...)
```

The parameter passed to the `reportDate` is a C# `DateTime` type variable, and there is no such thing as a `Date` type variable. I am getting the following error from the call:

> The conversion of a date data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value

The input field is not null.

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 0):

C# DateTime MinValue is `00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001.` but if I'm not mistaken SQL min datetime value is `1753-01-01 00:00:00.000`. You could get this error if you're trying to pass a value less than SQL min datetime. Also SQL max datetime is `9999-12-31 23:59:59.997` but C# max DateTime is `23:59:59.9999999, December 31, 9999`.

Update:

The error is for converting from date to datetime. `Date` in SQL has different limits to `datetime`, its range is `0001-01-01 through 9999-12-31` but datetime's range is as above. So whatever the value is, it's out of range for the `datetime` type, although as it's mentioned in the comments you're using date.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630352.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187819.aspx

Comment: Yeah, but he's using `DATE` in SQL Server which has a range of 1/1/0001 through 12/31/9999 ..... SQL Server `DATETIME` had a min value of `1/1/1753` - but **not** `DATE` or `DATETIME2` ....

Comment: @marc_s Yeah, true, didn't pay attention to that, I updated the answer. Thanks.